# can a function parameter be async in .net core 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, async-await, http-post

I was getting file from request body, Everything was working fine

**Working code:**

```
    [HttpPost("UploadImage/{reg_no}"), DisableRequestSizeLimit]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadImage1(int reg_no)
    {
        try
        {
            var formCollection = await Request.ReadFormAsync();
            var file = formCollection.Files[0];
```

then I wanted to do the same using parameter

```
    [HttpPost("UploadImage/{reg_no}"), DisableRequestSizeLimit]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadImage1(int reg_no, IFormFile profile_picture)
    {
        try
        {
            var file = profile_picture;
```

Is there any way I can make the 2nd way `await` for reading file?

Note: as @Matthew Watson suggested, if I want to do
`var file = await profile_picture;`
then the parameter
`IFormFile profile_picture` can't be changed to `Task<IFormFile> profile_picture` <strike>because it will not be detectable by swagger</strike>

TIA

Comment: You could pass in `Task<IFormFile> profile_picture` and do `var file = await profile_picture;`

Comment: @Matthew Watson if i say `IFormFile profile_picture` cant be changed is there any way to await?

Comment: No, the Action could not receive `Task<T>` like parameters.

Comment: What's your problem with the first approach?

Comment: its alright, but not detectable by swagger, so I dont want to use it

Comment: @Frost Swagger UI works fine with `IFormFile`, `List<IFormFile>` or even with embedded `IFormFile` [Reference](https://codeburst.io/file-upload-via-swagger-e6c21b54d036). So, why do you want to receive it as `Task<IFromFile>`?

Comment: @Peter Csala no no, `IFormFile` is good for me, i was saying is there any way i cant`await` for file ? like   `x = await formFile` instead of `x = formfile` . ( forget about return type `Task<IActionResult>` , consider it is `void`) . only I need to change the one line after try block

Comment: @Frost According to my knowledge either you receive the file(s) when the action is called or you retrieve it manually from the `Request`.

Comment: @Peter Csala can u explain  //when the action is called// , if I want that what should I do?

Comment: @Frost When the request is routed to your Action, so your 2nd example.